# Python select by attributes, location, copy features

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

Python script is failing. It's supposed to make a selection from a lyer based on attributes value and then select intersecting features of that selection and then make a copy of the selection as a new featureclass. I'm getting the error messages at the end but nothing in between and I can't figure out why. I got it working and then added some documentation and then it began failing again. I've tried running it from PythonWin and as a script tool in ArcMap and ultimately prefer to run it in the latter.

```
# this script selects digitized streets as well as the streets
# they intersect with from outdated centerline files and exports
# to a new featureclass to be merged with up to date centerline file

import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteoutput = True

try:
    # Enter parameters and run tool
    inPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    outPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    inPathFL = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inPath, "inPathFL")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inPathFL, "NEW_SELECTION", ' "Link_ID" <= 10000')
    arcpy.AddMessage("selecting features with link ID less than 10,000")
    arcpy.SelectLayerBylocation_management(inPathFL, "INTERSECT", inPathFL, "10 Feet", "ADD_TO_SELECTION")
    arcpy.AddMessage("selecting layers by location that intersect with currently selected features")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inPathFL, outPathFL)
    arcpy.AddMessage("copying features")

    # report a success message
    arcpy.AddMessage("Created source streets feature class!")

except:
    # get error messages
    arcpy.AddError("Could not complete the export for the intended selection")

    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
    print "Create source streets failed"
```

And here is the error message:

```
Executing: CreateSourceStreets CO_005_2012_Merge C:\RS_Data\Common\MapClips\CO_SF_2015Q2.gdb\CO_SF_2012_Source
Start Time: Tue Dec 08 15:38:11 2015
    Running script CreateSourceStreets...
    selecting features with link ID less than 10,000
    Could not complete the export for the intended selection
    Executing: SelectLayerByAttribute inPathFL NEW_SELECTION " "Link_ID" <= 10000"
    Start Time: Tue Dec 08 15:38:11 2015
    Succeeded at Tue Dec 08 15:38:11 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.05 seconds)
    Completed script CreateSourceStreets...
    Failed to execute (CreateSourceStreets).
    Failed at Tue Dec 08 15:38:11 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.76 seconds)
```

Comment: This will be easy to debug if you re-test the same code without the try/except functions that are masking the errors that Python and ArcPy provide.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of try and except gave me what i needed. SelcetBylocation needed to be changed to SelectByLocation (needed uppercase L).

Answer (score 0):

try the following on your SelectLayerByAttribute_management line
`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inPathFL, "NEW_SELECTION", """ "Link_ID" <= 10000""")`

The `"""` triple double quotes allow you to pass the Where Clause syntax properly.

Comment: Nope. Stil getting a message after select by attributes

Comment: I edited the answer @Shaun, it was supposed to be a triple double quote, not single quote. If this doesn't work I will test your whole code.